# How to add frequency percentages to a ordered barplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations, bar-chart, frequency

I need to build a horizontal barplot which is ordered and has the frequency counts (which i could get) as well as frequency percentages on top (side) of it.  The code I have so far looks something like this.  I have not been able to order the chart or add the percentages (in addition to the counts).  Any help is much appreciated.  I am sorry I am new here and do not have enough reputation to post an example picture.

```
event <- c("a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","c")
dat <- data.frame(event)


ggplot(dat, aes(x=event)) + geom_bar(fill = "orange", width = 0.5) + coord_flip() +
  geom_text(stat='bin',aes(label=..count..,vjust=.75, hjust = 0))
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Surely this has been asked an answered on SO. Did you do any searching?

Comment: Changing the order could be done by changing the factor beforehand: `dat$event <- factor(dat$event, levels = names(sort(table(dat$event))))`. And adding percentages works just like you did with absolute values: `geom_text(stat='bin', aes(label=paste0(..count.., ", ", round(..count../sum(..count..)*100, 1), "%")))`.

Comment: @lukeA – Thanks a lot.  Your explanation is right on and solved the issue I was having.

Comment: @BondedDust, I did search, but missed how to paste %s in addition to the counts.  Thanks.

Comment: Cool, I submitted the comment as an answer so you can mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the order could be done by changing the factor beforehand:

```
dat$event <- factor(dat$event, levels = names(sort(table(dat$event)))).
```

And adding percentages works just like you did with absolute values:

```
geom_text(stat='bin', 
      aes(label=paste0(..count.., 
                       ", ", 
                       round(..count../sum(..count..)*100, 1), 
                       "%")))
```